# Counting objects in an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array made of unlimited number of objects. These objects have the same structure. If I console.log my whole array I get something like this:

[object], [object], [object], ecc...

Whenever I push a new object inside of the array I could also implement a counter, or I could just use a normal for loop to count the objects. Isn't there any more efficient way to count all the objects?

Why does array.lenght not work?

Comment: why not? you probably just misspelled it (`array.lenght` ---> `array.length`).

Comment: I don't see why `array.length` wouldn't work, can you show an example?

Comment: Do you mean `array.length`? Could you please provide a code example?

Comment: JavaScript is spelling-sensitive.

Comment: Assuming you only misspelled `.length` in this post, and not in your code, I would guess you're not using an `Array`. You might be using an `Object` accidentally. Or you're literally using `Array.length` instead of `myArrayVariable.length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array.length` returns the number of elements stored inside an array.

Answer (score 1):

Most javascript engines will implement an efficient .length method for array objects natively. There is no need for you to duplicate their effort.

If you create an array, you can simply access `myArray.length` to get the length.

Example:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push({ 'id': 1, 'title': 'Who' });
myArray.push({ 'id': 2, 'title': 'What' });
myArray.push({ 'id': 3, 'title': 'Where' });
myArray.push({ 'id': 4, 'title': 'Why' });

alert(myArray.length); //should be 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use object.length. Consider this example:

```
x = [[], function() { return ""; }, 3,document.createElement('div')]
alert(x.length);
```

That prints "4" for me -- try it with your array and it should print out the proper number of objects in the array to your browser window if you're using javascript on the web... (otherwise just print x.length)

Perhaps posting more of your code will help. Oooh, btw, don't use "array.length" but use "x.length" assuming the x is the name or your array.